# Understanding interpretation of quantified set variables in Herbert Enderton "Second-order and Higher-order logic"

Tags: logic, model-theory, formal-languages, second-order-logic

In [Stanford Encyclopedia](https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/spr2008/entries/logic-higher-order/), concerning the semantics of second order logic, Herbert B. Enderton wrote

> ... an assignment $s$ of objects to the free variables in $\phi$. ... For a $k$-place predicate variable $P$,
>
> $M \models \forall P\; \phi[s]\;$ iff$\;$ for every $k$-ary relation
>   $Q$ on $A$, we have $M \models \phi[s']$
>
> where $s'$ differs from $s$ only in assigning the relation $Q$ to the
>   predicate variable $P$.

I think I understand informally what this means, but I am stuck when I try to understand how it works formally. Does the original assignment $s$ also assigns a value to the predicate variable $P$?  Naively, I would say no, because otherwise $\forall P$ is uninteresting (or else I misunderstand how assignments work), but the context seems to say the opposite.

Also, why do we need a second use of $\models$. Couldn't we say

$$M \models \forall P\; \phi[s]\; \iff \forall Q\; \phi^M[s]$$

where $\phi^M$ is the result of substituting the symbols in $\phi$ by their interpretation fixed in $M$, $P$ by $Q$, and the range of $Q$ is also fixed in $M$ (the possible ranges depend on the semantic) and $s$ assigns a value to all free variables in $\phi$, except $Q$, which is taken care by $\forall Q$.

I use the assumption that the formal language is very close to the language that is used to define the models, both have quantifiers, etc. So, I am trying to leverage on this. May be it is too naive. What am I  missing?

I am trying to understand how the formalism works. Also, again, why we need a second use of $\models$. If it was third order logic, would we need to use it three times? These two questions are most likely related. As usual, I must be missing some thing basic.

Comment: Correct : "an assignment $s$ of objects to the free variables in $φ$", as for FOL. The only difference is that, in SOL, we may have also *predicate* variables and *function* variables.

Comment: See [Enderton, page 283](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&printsec=frontcover) : "We must extend the
definition of satisfaction in the natural way. Let $V$ now be the set of **all** variables, individual, predicate, or function. Let $s$ be a function on $V$ that assigns to each variable the suitable type of object. Thus $s(v_1)$ is a member of the universe, $s(X^n)$ is an $n$-ary relation on the universe, and $s(F^n)$ is an $n$-ary operation."

Comment: Yes, I read the answer of Makholm and I realize that the formula to which s applies is $\forall P\, \phi$. This is what I missed, as far as what $s$ means is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble you're having is not really specific to *second-order* logic; you would run into exactly the same design issues when defining the semantics of quantifiers in ordinary *first-order* logic. If you already know some first-order logic, I think your problem is simply that the author of the article uses a different style than you're used to from the text you learned first-order logic from, but that difference would also exist for the plain first-order case.

Your basic problem, I think, is that you have not understood how the brackets and the $\vDash$ sign interact. Perhaps the spacing makes it unclear -- but the point here is that the author is explaining the semantics by defining a single *three-place* relation symbol
$$ {\rm something}_1 \vDash {\rm something}_2 \;[{\rm something}_3] $$
You can't in this context have a $\vDash$ without the $[\;]$, or $[\;]$ without the $\vDash$. (Well, actually these things probably have defined meanings by themselves, but that will be a *different definition* than the one you're looking at here).

In this three-place symbol,

- ${\rm something}_1$ is a structure, that is, an appropriate arranged collection of semantic objects
- ${\rm something}_2$ is always a *well-formed formula* consisting entirely of symbols, and with no trace of anything from $M$ appearing within it.
- ${\rm something}_3$ is a mapping from symbolic *names* to semantic objects that those names are imagined to stand for.

It differs between developments whether the map ${\rm something}_3$ is always assumed to map *every* variable symbol (of every sort) to an appropriate semantic object, or if it can be partial as long as it does define a meaning for everything that appears free in ${\rm something}_2$. Your quote would work under both of these conventions. Both give the same result in the case where ${\rm something}_2$ is a *sentence*, but there are minor technical advantages and disadvantages of each choice when it may have free variables in it. (It's like straightening out the kink in a carpet that's just a few centimeters too wide for the room: the slack has to go *somewhere*). When the work is done properly, the end result ends up being equivalent in either case.

The definition of the $\vDash\;[\;]$ relation is now by *recursion* in the structure of the formula ${\rm something}_2$. Thus, the definition of $\cdots\vDash\;\forall P.\varphi \;[\cdots]$ will naturally depend on an application of $\vDash\;[\;]$ to its subformula $\varphi$.

---

Your proposal

> $$M \models \forall P\; \phi[s]\; \iff \forall Q\; \phi^M[s]$$

seems to depend on building a $\phi^M$ which is something that contains a mixture of symbols and semantic objects. This *can* be made to work if you insist enough, but it is often considered inelegant and error-prone to mix syntax and semantics in that way.

Even worse, it seems like you're depending on $\forall Q$ to do its work *on the metalevel*, so if your proposal is to work we need to say that the quantifier in $\forall Q$ is *not* just a symbol.

In fact it looks like getting your proposal to work would require doing all of the *interesting* semantic work inside a definition of what $\varphi^M[s]$ actually *means*, in detail. And then $\vDash$ would just be a renaming of the thing that definition defines. All you would have achieved is to do the same work with different notation.

Comment: @Dominic108: After you do your substitution, does your substituted $\phi$ not contain symbols such as "$\to$" or "$\neg$"?

Comment: After some extra thoughts, I realize that it's just a question of notation. What I had in mind, was basically the same as in the Enderton definition.  I wrote $\forall Q$ and Enderton wrote "for every $k$-ary relation $Q$ on $A$". Next, I wrote $\phi^M[s]$, where $P$ is replaced by $Q$, but this is equivalent to $M \models \phi[s']$ where $s'$ ... .  So, what I wrote was also recursive. I just did not realize it.

Comment: And thankyou for your answer. It helped me to see that a recursive definition was a very natural thing, because the language is defined recursively and, in fact, my approach was not different.